# Getting rows outside of the foreach loop but comparing them inside of it (smarty template)

Tags: php, foreach, smarty, smarty3

Here is my issue - I have a page with comments, that looks something like that:

```
{foreach from=$comments item=row}
Here is the body of comment and like/unlike button
{/foreach}
```

And I need to check if user has already liked the comment and depending on that show like/unlike button. Normally in php I would do something like that:

```
- Query to retrieve all the comments from DB
- foreach loop to show them, like that:
foreach ($stmt as $comment) {
- another query inside of the foreach loop to find out data of users who 
 already liked this comment.
 - then if/else statement to choose which button to show
}
```

But since I'm using smarty I can't do any queries in foreach loop, while it's template and no logic code is allowed. What I need to check is:

```
{foreach from=$comments item=row}
{if {$comment_id} != {$row.id} && {$user_liked} != $user_id}
show like button
{/if}
{if {$comment_id} == {$row.id} && {$user_liked} == $user_id}
show dislike button
{/if}
{/foreach}
```

My DB structure so you understand what these rows mean:

```
Table `liking`:
-comment_id
-user_liked

Table `comments`:
-id
And $user_id is actually $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

So here's the question:
How do I get `comment_id` and `user_liked`    rows from `liking` table outside of the foreach loop with comments, so I can compare them inside of the loop with comments?
I tried to fetch them all, and get them with another foreach loop inside of the comments foreach loop, but it just isn't working right. `Smarty` engine is cool, but when it comes to such things it's really disappointing... Thanks everyone who will try to help me, I will be glad to hear any advise or suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the liking table in php code when fetch comment talbe.
eg:

```
select comment.*,(select count(*) from liking where liking.comment_id=comment.id and liking.user_liked={$_SESSION("user_id")) as liked from comment
```

and in smarty:

{foreach from=$comments item=row}
{if $row.liked==0}
show like button
{else}
show dislike button
{/if}
{/foreach}

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But for now all I got is this - `Warning: Illegal string offset 'liked'`

Comment: you have to check you php code,the liked field did not assign to smarty.can you paste more code here ?